# Control a single Form from 2 different forms on c#

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have the following:
**FormA**, **FormB**, **FormCtrl**

When **FormA** loads, **FormCtrl** is shown:

```
FormCtrl fc = new FormCtrl();
fc.Show();
```

From **FormA**, I can control **Panel1** on **FormCtrl** and I can also load **FormB**:

```
FormB fb = new FormB();
fb.Show();

fc.Panel1.Visible = true;
```

From **FormB**, I need to control **Panel2** on **FormCtrl**:

```
fc.Panel2.Visible = true; // I don't know how to do this :)
```

Comment: why don't you pass that `fc` instance as constructor injection argument

Comment: As long as FormCtrl exists somewhere in your application you can use `FormCtrl fc = Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormCtrl>().FirstOrDefault();` to get access to it anywhere in your application.

Comment: Object spaghetti is dangerous.  You need a controller, the C in MVC.  Winforms does not enforce any particular MVC pattern.  Standard approach is to make the main form also the controller.  Which works here since it has a reference to both forms.  Use an event in FormB to notify the main form that it needs to C.

Comment: ok I managed to Show/Hide FormCtrl from FormB. @Rahul I passed the instance form FormA to FormB. One problem is that I can't access Panel1 or Panel2 on FormCtrl from FormB. The every object modifier on FormCtrl is set to Public.

Comment: @HansPassant can you please help me on how to make the controller? URLs are good too :)

Comment: I don't agree with exposing controls to other forms. Add methods and properties to get or set the values you need, and let the form handle the visual changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with communication between containers is to implement an observer class

The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. (Wikipedia)

the way i do this is creating an Observer class, and inside it write something like this:

```
1    public delegate void dlFuncToBeImplemented(string signal);
2    public static event dlFuncToBeImplemented OnFuncToBeImplemented;
3    public static void FuncToBeImplemented(string signal)
4    {
5         OnFuncToBeImplemented(signal);
6    }
```

so basically: the first line says that there would be a function that somebody else will implement

the second line is creating an event that occurs when the delegated function will call

and the third line is the creation of the function that calls the event

so in your Form that you want to change from outside(FormCtrl), you should add a function like this:

```
    private void ObserverRegister()//will contain all observer function registration
    {
        Observer.OnFuncToBeImplemented += Observer_OnFuncToBeImplemented;
        /*and more observer function registration............*/
    }

    void Observer_OnFuncToBeImplemented(string signal)//the function that will occur when  FuncToBeImplemented(signal) will call 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Signal "+signal+" received!", "Atention!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
```

and in your other Forms (FormA, FormB) you should do something like:

```
public static int signal = 0;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Observer.FuncToBeImplemented(signal);//will call the event in the user control
}
```

and now, you can register this function to a whole bunch of other controls and containers and they will all get the signal

I hope this would help :)

Answer (score 1):

Surely it is bad practice, however you can pass a reference to FormCtrl like so:

```
public partial class FormB: Form
{
    public FormCtrl Reference { get; set; }

    public FormB(FormCtrl referencedForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Reference = referencedForm;

        Reference.Panel2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```